# GitHub commits aren't recorded in the 'Your Contributions` calendar

Tags: git, github

I've been making continuous commits to my `GitHub` repos from my Linux shell and they show up nicely on the website just as they should. The only problem is that "Your Contributions" section doesn't show any recent activity. I have one green square from some day in November which I don't know how I got but all the other contributions don't show up in the calendar (but again, they **do**  show up in their repos).

What am I missing here?

[My github site](https://github.com/roey-angel)

Comment: Do you commit to private repo?

Comment: no, all my repos are public

Comment: This question is better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the interface/accounts work) or direct to GitHub:Support

Comment: Actually, @harsh gave the best answer

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is a Github issue where sometimes their update mechanisms don't work and it turns into a "stale cache". This is nothing serious, simply send an email to support@github.com describing the issue and they'll fix it right away.

Comment: Github now requires, new support requests be created using their Support website:

https://support.github.com/contact

Answer (score 186):

For me this problem was caused by me committing from my work computer where I was using a different email in my gitconfig.  Adding my work email address to my github account didn't make the past commits show up in the summary, but new commits are now showing up as they should.

You can find the email address you are using for a repository with `git config user.email`.

Comment: I've got the same situation, this is weird, should they attach the commit to userid instead of Email, which we could change.

Comment: This is the most likely answer - I have seen this happen before even though commits and PR's are going through just fine -

Comment: Thanks very much - this was exactly the problem I was happening. Did a `git config user.email <my email>` and pushed a commit, and now it's tracking my commits. I'll write their support next, since I have days where I worked 14 hours, making a new repo and getting a whole alpha version written, yet I only have activity for the issues I opened against it.

Comment: @turtlemonvh It is possible to link different emails to different repos. So if you were using your work computer but have a personal project repo "personal_project" and another repo "work_project", you could configure separate email IDs for them both.

Go to the repo directory on the terminal and do the following  


`$pwd
personal_project
$git config user.email "your personal email"

$pwd
work_project
$git config user.email "work email"`
That should count your contributions correctly.

Comment: This is probably should be the accept answer. FYI, you can change git's history. Here are instructions from github: [changing-author-info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/)

Comment: I had the same issue. After adding email to git config contribution started coming. But the contributions only show from the time I changed the email in git config. Is there a way to show contribution made mean while when my wrong email was configured.

Comment: After I added my working email to GitHub profile, I saw all my activities. It's because I worked with Git by my works email address.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and after adding my work email to GitHub emails I can see my contributions now. 

Also, anyone reading this in the future, use the `noreply` email provided by GitHub for `Git Command Line` commits. This way you can keep your primary email private and at the same time can track your contributions.

Comment: He is correct, you need to place/set your email ID in your local computer (terminal) using this command `git config user.email <your email>`. After you set that, try pushing your code to remote branch. It should work.

Answer (score 126):

from git

> I've just had a peek at your contributions for the GoTime2 repository
>   and it seems that you've been pushing commits to the layout branch.
>
> The reason why those contributions are not showing up is that we only
>   track commit contributions when they are made to the repository's
>   default branch or gh-pages branch:
>
> https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#which-contributions-are-counted
>
> Once your contributions are merged into the default or gh-pages, you
>   will get credited for them on the date you authored them.

**so in my case I had to merge my 'layout' branch with the 'master' branch to see the 'your contributions' show up in the calendar.**

Comment: I work in my own branch a lot, and then merge into the 'master' branch, but my contributions still aren't showing up. Any ideas?

Edit: for some reason my email address was set to a different email in the application I use to manage my git repositories (SourceTree).   I've added that email address to my GitHub account, but still not seeing any changes.  I'm hoping it just takes a while for them to recalculate the stats.

Comment: @robert.bo.roth ~"Once you link emails, you might need to contact support so that they can backfill your previous contributions."
Source - http://git.io/NtUV5A

Comment: What if I made commits to another branch and then the owner of the repo merged them into `master` branch. Would my contributions recorded in the 'Your Contributions` calendar?

Comment: Late, so you probably know now, but in case this is of benefit to anyone else: @soshial yes, this is the case :) it backdates and acknowledges after they have been merged in, as far as I've noticed.

Comment: The same happened to me. After merging to the default branch, the contributions appeared immediately. Thank you

Comment: In my case I changed the default branch and now whenever I push commits to it the contributions do not show up.

Comment: I followed up this blog – https://blog.tinned-software.net/rewrite-author-of-entire-git-repository/ it updated my email correctly, verified in commit.patch url. But still it contributions didn't show up, then I merged all commits to the default branch, the contributions appeared immediately. Thanks.

Comment: I see now. I wish there was an option for tracking precise commit hashes, because I think the reason for this behaviour is that they do not want to double count the same stuff. Okay, admittedly, a squashed commit would break this method.

Answer (score 48):

A possible cause for this:

> **Commit was made in a fork**
>
> Commits made in a fork will not count toward your contributions.

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Comment: Any idea what the reasoning is behind this? The forks can still be public and could still be contributing something novel to the community.

Answer (score 31):

This did the trick! I just used `$ git config user.email "my email address used on my git repo"` and it worked.

Answer (score 27):

"You have to commit the changes with the same email id you used to login to your github account"

**How to solve:**

- Change global email id for all repositories using following command.

> git config --global user.email abc@xyz.com

- Or Change email id for one particular repository. From inside the particlar repository run below command

> git config user.email abc@xyz.com

- Or in the repository open .git/config file and edit

> email = abc@xyz.com
>   name = abc

other causes can be found here
https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Answer (score 22):

so this usually happens due to a lot of factors, for which you must visit this [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#which-contributions-are-counted)

***The most common mistakes I found were :***

1. Email not configured properly on local machine. (your laptop/pc).
2. Forking.
3. Not using default or gh-pages branch for commit.

I personally had issue 1 recently, for which I went to my **terminal/cmd/cli** and configure my email address locally by running this command

```
git config --global user.email yourname@email.address
```

Once that's done, try running this config again like this:

```
git config --global user.email
```

You should be able to see:

```
yourname@email.address
```

*If this was correct, you have successfully configured your local machine with your global public repo. Now your next commit will be credited towards your calendar.*

Comment: Thanks for the fix @aasmin ali

Answer (score 15):

Make sure your local email is the exact same that the one in the account.

Go to the terminal and inside the folder you are pushing the commits, run:

```
git config --global user.email
  #=> TRICULI.TO@MAIL.com

git config --system user.email
  #=> 

git config --local user.email
  #=> triculito@mail.com
```

Something similar was happening to me. The email in my account was the one in the --global, but my --local was slightly different, it had not '.'.

(In Gmail there is no difference between those emails, they work the exact same).

Comment: This worked for me.  My global was correct but system and local emails blank.  Added those two and now my commits show up.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe Github had fixed this problem. There is one simple way, go to github.com email setting: https://github.com/settings/emails

> Personal settings --> Emails

**You can add email address there, and verify your newer email address with send a verification link, then you will find your previous commits are all recorded in the 'Your Contributions` calendar.** And this email verification will also let you receive notifications and password resets from GitHub.

Your new email address will be used for account-related notifications (e.g. account changes and billing receipts) as well as any web-based GitHub operations (e.g. edits and merges).

Comment: Nice to see all my hard work finally shown again... :)

Comment: This is what I did and it worked like a charm. I saw all my old commits that I thought were "missing"!

Comment: I've done this. But still can't see my work on the graph. :( Am I missing something? `then you will find your previous commits are all recorded in the 'Your Contributions` calendar` <- This statement doesn't seem to be right. Does this step takes time?

Comment: I've fixed my contribution problem, by contacting Github's support. Yes, I've checked my email address is correct.

Comment: After doing this I was finally able to see the additional 600 contributions I have made this year. I honestly thought GitHub would track using my commit credentials not the git config. Good to now now. I had my work email on my home dev machine and I was committing to my personal GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue in Xcode 9 for iOS development.

In Github, I noticed a non-committer author.
[image]

Even though I made commits in Xcode.
There was no contributions in the 'Your Contributions` Calendar.

Solution:

**Change Committer Name and Email Globally**
**The email address used for the commits must be associated with your GitHub account.**

In the Terminal:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Full Name"
$ git config --global user.email "fullname@gmail.com"
```

See also GitHub Help: [Setting your commit email address in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/)

Answer (score 7):

**I solved it by making two changes**

1. I configured my local machine using command `git config --global user.email "your github email"`
2. I changed my default branch of my project repo from `main to master` using github website @ https://github.com/your-username/your-repo-name/settings/branches

`

Answer (score 6):

I've just added my email again through the command line and it solves the issue:

```
$ git config user.email "myemail@mydomain.com"
```

And another issue is regarding your branch. If you create another branch beside maser and try to push that branch this issue might occur. In my case I have started pushing to master and got the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Adding **secondary email to GitHub** helped not only with the current problem but also to retrieve past commits/contributions.

If the email on the local machine doesn't match the one in the GitHub account - GitHub will not populate the contributions.
As it was answered before, run the following command to determine which email is being used on the local machine: `git config user.email`.
Proceed to https://github.com/settings/emails and add a secondary email, that you will find on your local machine.

Comment: I did as Vadym said, and all of my contributions showed up retroactively.  My contribution calendar matrix used to have only a few green squares, now it is as green as a prairie field in the spring.

Answer (score 5):

I had issues seeing attributions for commits on a private repo that was added to my organization after many of my commits occurred (new commits were showing up properly) and was only able to get them to show up by removing the email address from my profile, then re-adding the same email address.

It seems like doing this cleared up a caching issue within GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I previously changed my email address on GitHub and I forgot to change the local one, too.

Answer (score 4):

I hade to manually add my email to SourceTree settings even if `git config` had the right email address configured. Only after doing this, GitHub started recording my commits to my contribution graph.

[image: SourceTree Settings Screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me. This option is under settings->advanced->User Information in the latest version of SourceTree. I just removed check and wrote github nickname and email address.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exact problem, turns out it is because the email on my local git does not match the email on my GitHub account.

To update the email on your local machine:

```
git config --global user.email "your.email@email.com"
```

Verify that all your commits are updated on your github, if not you can check individual commits to see what email the commit is associated with by clicking on the commit and adding ".patch" to the end of the commit url like this:

```
https://github.com/username/repoName/commit/9fbe83f71cfc3503.patch
```

Now all you have to do is add that email you see to your account.(It does not need to be verified)

Check the commit again and you should see your username and credited :)

Answer (score 4):

The "Contributions Calendar" or "Activity overview" on github is only recording the commits that are related to the mail address that is recorded in the github account.

### Change the mail address for all future commits

As already noted by many others in this thread, look up the current locally saved email address by:

```
git config user.email
```

If it doesn't match the mail on github, change using:

```
git config --global user.email my_email@gmail.com
```

This will globally change the mail address for all future commits but will not affect the "Contributions Overview" for the past ones. You can follow the [official docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address) for an extended description.

### Change the mail address to update the overview for the past commits

You realize that many of your past commits have not been recorded correctly in the Github "Contributions Overview":
[image]

To change that, you can change the author info for the repositories by following the steps explained [in the official github docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info).

A short summary:

1. Open git bash
2. Clone a bare repository

   ```
   git clone --bare https://github.com/user/repo.git
   cd repo.git
   ```
3. Paste the following code into the git bash console after changing the variables `OLD_EMAIL`, `CORRECT_NAME` and `CORRECT_EMAIL`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   git filter-branch --env-filter '

   OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
   CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
   CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

   if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
   then
   export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
   export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
   fi
   if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
   then
   export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
   export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
   fi
   ' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
   ```
4. Press enter to run the script
5. Push the corrected history to github

   ```
   git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
   ```

This procedure should update the "Contributions Overview" and now also show the commits not shown before:
[image]

**Warning**: *This action is destructive to your repository's history. If you're collaborating on a repository with others, it's considered bad practice to rewrite published history. You should only do this in an emergency.*

Answer (score 4):

GitHub clearly states how they measure your contributions in their [Help](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile):

- ***Issues and Pull Requests:***

  - Only if they were opened in a standalone repository, not a fork
- ***Commits:***
  Only if they meet all of the following conditions:

  - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account
  - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork
  - The commits were made:

    - In the repository's default branch (usually master)
    - In the gh-pages branch (for repositories with project sites)

  In addition, at least one of the following must be true:

  - You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository
  - You have forked the repository
  - You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository
  - You have starred the repository

***Note:*** After making a commit that meets the requirements to count as a contribution, you may need to wait for up to 24 hours to see the contribution appear on your contributions graph

Comment: This (In the repository's default branch (usually master)) makes total sense now, exactly the reason why my contributions still don't display. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this worked for me: GitHub contribution checker, link below.
Once installed, the program checks the validity of your recent commits and gives you a list of rules, with the rule/rules not met in red.

My problem was GitHub was using a Cygwin terminal name as an email address so I just added my Cygwin terminal name to my profile and all recent commits were added to my GitHub calendar.

**Your commit will not be counted as a contribution! Check the details below:** 
https://github.com/jdennes/contribution-checker

Answer (score 3):

You can go to https://github.com/settings/emails
and add the email that you are using with git config --global user.email

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem, mine was fixed by setting the email

```
git config --global user.email jonathan.m2ndoza@gmail.com
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution was pretty simple. I had the wrong email set for the global email config

```
git config --global user.email "email@yourmail.com"
```

> Just make sure the above email and your GitHub account email are same

Answer (score 3):

**I contacted Github Team** for the same issue and this was their response hope this helps some of you

Contributions are counted if they meet certain criteria, described here:

https://docs.github.com/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

You can find out why a specific commit to a public repository is not counting as a contribution using this app:

https://contribution-checker.herokuapp.com/
this contribution checker is very helpful it solved my problem

People often find they are missing contributions because their commits were authored by an email address that is not associated with their GitHub account, as described here:

https://docs.github.com/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

You can check the author of a commit by adding .patch to the end of the commit URL, like this:

https://github.com/github/linguist/commit/cfd5cbaba00122fceea1cfb108c5bdc3d451065a.patch

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the similar issue by Using GitHub profile's username as my git username in my local environment.

As a example,

> https://github.com/susithrj

set global username as **susithrj** in your local git config.

> git config --global user.name "susithrj"

Answer (score 1):

I had to restore my laptop recently and forgot to reconfig my email to git. My laptop username looks similar to my git one, so I just blindly thought my commits were being attributed correctly. As posted, you can change your global email settings. However, if you want to correct the miss-attributed commits on your project, you can use this run this script to create an alias `gca` that you can run in your git project directory to change the authorship of your past commits.

From your `~` directory, add:

```
$ cat <<EOF >> ~/.aliases
 function git_change_authorship {
 git filter-branch -f --env-filter "
  GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=\"\$1\"
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=\"\$2\"
  GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=\"\$1\"
  GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=\"\$2\"
 "
 }
 alias gca=git_change_authorship
 EOF

 $ source ~/.aliases
```

then in your git project directory run `gca <git username> <git email address>`

Heads up! I have only used this in my own personal projects where I have been the sole committer. Haven't had a chance to test it out with group projects, so proceed cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the "Insights" section/tab of my repository, and instead of my current user, there was a anonymous user (which was also me), so I changed the email config in my current computer to the one that I use github with as described above.

[image: Insigths]

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your email private and still have the contributions show up in your calendar. You  can choose to keep your email address private from the [*github email settings*](https://github.com/settings/emails)  and use the *github noreply email address* in your git config.

```
git config user.email "xxxxxxxxxxx@users.noreply.github.com"
```

**Note**

For me, I had chosen to keep my email private from the *github email settings*.
This gave me an error

```
Your push would publish a private email address.
```

while trying to push to my repo. I removed the email. Pushing after this was successful but the contributions were not recorded in my calendar.

As mentioned by GitHub in the email settings page

> We’ll remove your public profile email and use
>   xxxxxxxxxxx@users.noreply.github.com when performing
>   web-based Git operations (e.g. edits and merges) and sending email on
>   your behalf. If you want command line Git operations to use your
>   private email you must [set your email in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the the user flag.
For example
`git push -u origin`
instead of
`git push`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and figured out that I was not pushing to the origin/main branch, rather to some other branch. I solved it by merging the two branches. In addition, even if the two branches are merged, if the `origin/main` branch is behind several commits, still the contribution section would not update. one still need to do merging (kind of) to make sure that `origin/main` branch is updated all the time, do:

*Note: (this solution will easily work for the local repo which is pulling from one remote and pushing to a different targeted repo (problamacic one))*

1. `git pull origin main:temp`

   - This will pull the main to a temp branch (temp is local branch), but still `origin/main` branch is behind several commits if one is pushing in more than one branch system. We need to chekout to temp branch to merge/move it forwards (so to speak)
2. `git checkout temp`

   - it will turn from: `(origin/main, origin/HEAD, temp)`  to->>>>>>>> `(HEAD -> temp, origin/main, origin/HEAD)` this means now HEAD is pointing to `temp` branch, so we can make it move forwards (so to speak) several commits (or merge whichever the case may be).
3. `git merge branch-second`

   - Now we want to merge to branch-second: `(origin/branch-second, main, branch-second)`  locally, which is several commits above temp after merge looks like this: `(HEAD -> temp, origin/branch-second, main, branch-second)`
4. `git push origin temp:main`

   - Now push temp to main in the origin (origin means remote):
5. `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` shows:

   - `(HEAD -> temp, origin/main, origin/HEAD, origin/branch-second, main, branch-second)`

###### so, the origin/main is merged and pushed to branch-second and all are at the same levels, and contribution started to show up:) hope it saves your time

checkout my medium article on the same:
[Medium](https://yogender027mae.medium.com/commits-are-not-visible-on-the-github-contribution-section-of-my-github-profile-717c03a6ef80)

Comment: Why would you want to do this incredibly convoluted detour which desynchronises the remote `main` branch with your local `main` branch? In general that’s an incredibly bad idea. Instead, you want to keep the main branch synchronised between your local repo and the remote, and merge changes into the local `main` branch (and then push that) as once the changes are ready to be merged.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes `agree!` I think, there could be instances when the local repo is `pulling (fetching)` from one and pushing to another (targeted repo). So one can push to the targeted repo (problematic repo) from the current `main` branch local, but the `main` local branch is synchronized with the `main` remote branch of the repo it's pulling from.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to the **repository setting**s and go to **Default branch section** and click the **switch button** and choose the **other branch** and **save it**.

- Make sure your changes are notified to all who are contributing to
  the repo.

Answer (score 0):

for me was the file within the project:

```
/.git/config

...
[user]
    name = your user
    email = user@host.com
...
```

Inside the block [user] double-check the 'email' is correct (mine was incorrect) and the name is unique (mine was duplicated).

To double-check with contributor is increasing use:

```
git shortlog -sn
```

make a push, check which one is increasing the counter and that name should be the name inside the block [user]

Answer (score 0):

To those who still can't make it work after type in correct(you think) email and name in git config:

**Remove the quotation marks that wrap the email and name.**

This works for me, careless me..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my error by :

I had uploaded the repo using :
`git remote add url "my-repo-link"`
`git push url master`

using **url instead of origin** did not show any green dots even after push ,
So , I created another repo , and re-init and commit and this time I write :
`git remote add origin "my-repo-link"`
`git push origin master`

All my previous commit to my ex-repo also added in my new repo ...saved my work and time

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in your VS Code github logined with same email.
2. If you are working on different  branch so merge it to the main branch all the contributions will show.