# GitHub is not showing contributions to private repos enabled for inclusion on profile

Tags: git, github, repository

I have been using git through bash commands to push my commits to some of my private repositories. I realized that even after enabling "Include private contributions on my profile" the contributions are not being updated. However, when I add a new file inside the same repositories using github.com, the commits are somehow counted.

Can someone help me to have all commits being acknowledged as contributions.

I use the following commands on bash:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/my_username/repo_name.git
> ```
>
> git pull origin master
>
> git add file_name
>
> git commit -m "message"
>
> git push origin master

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may check that the email used when committing is included in the email setting at Github.

This [article](https://help.github.com/en/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile) describes in more details the conditions for contribution.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289768/github-commits-arent-recorded-in-the-your-contributions-calendar) may also be relevant.

Comment: After a lot of troubleshooting attempts, I realized that I had changed my GitHub email id to enable student benefits but hadn't changed my git tool to reflect the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Contributions & Activity

```
check: Include private contributions on my profile(option)
```

Answer (score 0):

Private repository contributions are not count on github graph when another user is viewing your profile, but whenever you change the visibility of your repository to public, it reveals all and display to the github graph