# Ghost Contributor on Github (Github Bug)

Tags: github

**Hello StackOverflow.**
I came across a strange **bug** on Github.

Repository [Link](https://github.com/ishtiaqSamdani/GoHealthy)

I created a repository 4 months ago.
And added only 2 contributors to that repository.

• I didn’t add anymore contributors But There is **another** contributor added.

[image: ScreenShot of Contributor]

• I tried to remove that contributor but **couldn’t find him on Collaborators & Teams** - Manage Access

[image: ScreenShot of Contributor Page]

Comment: The automatic listed contributors are all people that did some commits on your repo. This guy did one commit: https://github.com/ishtiaqSamdani/GoHealthy/commit/9e3b0170999c8e736abb96aa3b6d4725a9077685.
The contributors you can administrate have special rights on the repo (e.g. merging PRs, closing issues, creating release and so on). But not everyone who contributed code to your repo should have these rights.
Albei being named similarly they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the **Branch protection rule** by enabling **Require approvals** under Settings > Branches > Branch protection rules > Require a pull request before merging > Require approvals.

Answer (score 0):

That's maybe because he made a commit and you/your team accepted his pull request

Comment: That's the problem Mr.Raman no one has pulled anything and more over that person's last activity on GitHub was on December 3rd, 2021
[YushaBinArif](https://github.com/YushaBinArif)

Comment: c.f. https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile
`You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.`
Since he's not a collaborator as stated per your question, this commit is not counted in his contributions/activities.

Answer (score 0):

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15289768/14414324).

It seems that GitHub uses the email address to list the contributors. Looking at the [patch](https://github.com/ishtiaqSamdani/GoHealthy/commit/9e3b0170999c8e736abb96aa3b6d4725a9077685.patch) and a random one from [YushaBinArif](https://github.com/YushaBinArif) like [this one](https://github.com/YushaBinArif/Tetris/commit/f66e09a7cc40f2867cf03ffd20188ee5e9dbb1f3.patch) both use the same email address.

Add `.patch` at the end of the commit URL to see the patch.